# Centos Kernel compilation: systemd fails to start udev

Tags: centos, kernel, compile, kernel-module

For my Centos 7.7 VM, I compiled kernel version 4.4 to just see how it works.
I downloaded the kernel code from this site https://www.kernel.org/

And followed the procedure that I found here : https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

All steps worked perfectly but rebooting with new kernel gives me 'Systemd failed to start udev device manager' error. So, system does not boot. Here is the screenshot of udev problem during reboot:

[image]

How can I troubleshoot and fix this error ?

Comment: Did you actually import the CentOS kernel config, or did you start with a fresh configuration?

Comment: I imported my existing kernel config. Current version is 3.10

Comment: I even don't know if it's possible to update major version directly from 3.10 to 4.4...